# JSON Object to DataBase with ASP.NET

Tags: sql, asp.net, json

I have managed to store a Json file to my database using c#, I created a Model for every value for a Json like this :

```
[{
"id": "1",
"val1": "Json2 Test2",
"val2": "Json2 Test2",
"val3": "Json2 Test2",
"val4": "Test2"
 },
 {
 same
 }]
```

But I have another Json like this :

```
"count": 2,
"value": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "val1": "aaa",
        "val2": "aaaa",
        "collection": {
            "id": "2",
            "val1": "bbbb",
            "val2": "bbb"
        },
        "collection2": {
            "id": "3",
            "val1": "cccc",
            "val2": "cccc"
    },
    {
        same
    }]
```

My model in cs in basically the same and for the collection I use

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "collection1")]
    public IList<string> Collection1 { get; set; }
```

But I don't see how I can upload all this Json in my DataBase. Should I create another table for collection1 and collection2 ?
I use this also :

```
string data = streamReader.ReadToEnd();    
List<Json1> json1= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Json1>>(data);
```

Thank you for the help

Comment: Why the <sql> tag?

Comment: Potentially yes you could create more tables. It's an obvious solution. Another option is simply to store the JSON string in a field. But it's really up to you though: we don't understand the meaning of the data, or what you need to store in order to fulfil your application's requirements, or what you want to do with the data after it's been stored. What you do is almost entirely a decision based on contextual information we don't have available to us.

Comment: OK thank you @ADyson i think i will create other tables then

Comment: If you will have nested values, you'd better think in having an unique table with a relation to itself, thus you can keep as many nested levels as you need.

Comment: Some databases, like Postgresql, can store json types.  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/datatype-json.html  Is using such a database an option for you?

Comment: I don't mind using Postgresql but I think the best approach with the implementation I want to do is using a unique table with a relation to itself.